# How to use ANTS registration tool?

Tags: image-processing, medical, image-registration

I am working medical image segmentation. I have T1-weighted MRIs of 120 patients with their corresponding label volumes (altogether 240 volumes). I have not worked with image-registration. I installed [ANTS](https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTs/wiki/ANTS-and-antsRegistration) but I do not know how to apply registration on these MRIs. I am confused with few questions:

1. Which patient should be considered as `fixed` and which one `moving`? What is the criteria for such choosing?
2. Since this is segmentation task, the ground truth images should be registered as well? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find out the solution from the [ANTS wiki page](https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTs/wiki/Anatomy-of-an-antsRegistration-call).